# I am having a trick with the size of my button's icon

Tags: icons, size, codenameone

I am trying to set icon for some element like a button in my projet,
First of all, i have added a quick image icon

But when i try to set this icon to a button, it is too big and it is not very good at all

```
what can i do in this case?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resize image to a specific size with https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Image.html#scaledHeight(int)

or use multiimages - https://codenameone.com/how-do-i---fetch-an-image-from-the-resource-file---add-a-multiimage.html